# Explanation on Data Disk

Tags: azure, vps, disk

I asked this question and received this answer.. However, I don't understand how to do the answer so I need clarification and more explanation

**"I want to make 20 Virtual Computers and I want to download same files on them, however it will take too long time to get on each one of them and download the same files. Is there anyway I can have the files already downloaded on the other Virtual machines that I will create so I don't have to re-download on each single one?"**

Answer was!

**The Data Disk
I haven't actually done this myself, so some independent work will be required. Nutshell:
You can upload an arbitrary .vhd to the cloud and create a data disk out of it, so on a local VM add a new static disk (Azure doesn't import dynamic vhds last I checked) and download everything you want to that VHD. Then upload that VHD to your storage and print out a data disk for every VM from the disk image that you uploaded. Done!**

I don't know how to do that answer, can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google..

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj672979.aspx#bk_UploadDisk

you should asked on the question you orignally asked for some clarafication.